# UIPanGestureRecognizer to drag Image View - scale blows up if I drag a second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to have it so the Image View gets smaller as it is dragged and then reset when the user stops dragging. It works perfectly the first time, but on the second drag the frame of the UIImage goes above 100% (ie above 200x200 in this case). Please advise. I have tried a lot of things and as you can see, I have been printing to console to see what is going on but I just cant figure out why frame gets bigger on second time. THANKS!

```
var xFromCenter: CGFloat = 0
var mainPic = UIImageView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.mainPic.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width / 2 - 100, self.view.bounds.height / 2, 200, 200)
    self.mainPic.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.view.addSubview(self.mainPic)

    var gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDragged:"))
    mainPic.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    mainPic.userInteractionEnabled = true

}

func wasDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
    var mainPic = gesture.view!

    xFromCenter += translation.x

    var scale = min(80 / abs(xFromCenter), 1)

    mainPic.center = CGPoint(x: mainPic.center.x + translation.x, y: mainPic.center.y)

    gesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

    mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.view.transform, scale, scale)

    println(xFromCenter)
    println(scale)
    println(self.mainPic.frame)

    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

        self.mainPic.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width / 2 - 100, self.view.bounds.height / 2, 200, 200)

        xFromCenter = 0

        println(xFromCenter)
        println(scale)

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the touch methods of uiview instead of a pan gesture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the scale before you reset the size.

Like so:

```
if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
    // Add this line:
    self.mainPic.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    self.mainPic.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width / 2 - 100, self.view.bounds.height / 2, 200, 200)
...
```

I tested this (in xcode 6.3) and it worked.